# Flutter setState rebuilding whole page efficacy

Tags: flutter

I was wondering how `setState()` really works in Flutter.

I have a page that contains a ListView and a Play button. When I press the button, I call `setState()` to change the Icon from the button. This triggers the ListView to rebuild the whole list which it's items.

Should I wrap my button in a new StatefulWidget, so rebuilding the button won't rebuild the whole page? Or is Flutter smart enough to figure out what has really changed and only rebuild these widgets? If the letter is the case, how does it work? I'm sure the build method of my List items is being called...

Answer (score 0):

You should know more about *Reactive programming* and *Streams* in Flutter. *Reactive programming* is architecture around the notion of *Streams* and listeners. *Streams* allow you to rebuild only one specific element, it's much more efficient!

Video from Google I/O '18 about it:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI

Great post that explain the notions of *Streams* and *Reactive Programming*:

https://www.didierboelens.com/2018/08/reactive-programming---streams---bloc/

It's intermediate difficulty method, but it's worth to learn it!

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks but I know about reactive programming. But what are you recommending. Do you suggest that I use a Stream for my Button Icon and a StreamBuilder so I don't need to call setState when pressing the button? I know I can do it this way but my main question was more if I really need to do this or if flutter know what needs to be rebuild...

Comment: @Jonas When you call `setState` it calls rebuild method of this StatefulWidget, where it was called. So now you can choose, where you will call `setState`. If you call it in `Widget` that draws whole window, then it will rebuild all window. If you make custom Button (StatefulWidget), and call `setState` in this Button, then only Button will be rebuilt. But in the last option you are combining Business Logic and displaying graphic - it's not so good. So you must use _Streams_ and don't use `setState`, if you want rebuild specific element in good and efficient way :)

Comment: Alright, I thought I read sometime ago that flutter is smart enough to figure out what has changed and what should and should not be rebuild. If thats not the case, I need to make sure, what should and shouldn't be rebuild manually.